# Back UIButton Controlling UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I have looked everywhere for this.

I have a navigation controller. I like using the navigation controller with all the animation however the bar irritates me so i have disabled it.

I would like to create a UIButton that will push the navigation controller back a page instead.

Is this possible? can someone tell me how to achieve this and get hold of the correct item that allows to push back to the previous view.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a button with a target on a function that do:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Since navigation controller works as a stack your current view controller is poped out from the stack and the previous view controller is showed

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [UINavigationController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you can have your UIButton call the navigation controller's popViewControllerAnimated:

Answer (score 0):

Did you try these methods in the UINavigationController class:

```
– pushViewController:animated:
– popViewControllerAnimated:
– popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
– popToViewController:animate
```

Call the pop methods from your button's action method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a valid reference to the Nav Controller, set up the button action to use:

> Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```